# Google Translate : Case dependant translation?

Tags: google-translate

I tried to translate the English noun *hint* to French and I was surprised to get three different translations, depending on if I inputted *hint*, *Hint* or *HINT* (resp. *soupçon*, *Astuce* and *CONSEIL*).

My question is not about the translation but about why Google Translate seems to use case sensitive translations? In which case should it be useful?

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitive translations can be useful when translating from English, and the word case can indicate a different word, just spelled the same.  Consider these examples:

> polish - a process to make something shiny
>
> Polish - someone from Poland
>
> french - a way of slicing vegetables
>
> French - nationality of someone from France

Add in acronyms, which are usually all caps, and that meaning can also change:

> wow - exclamation of something cool
>
> WOW - World of Warcraft

This may not be the reason Google is considering case.  But it is an answer for why it might be useful.